# The auxService:mapreduce_shuffle does not exist

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hdfs, sqoop, hadoop-yarn

When I am trying to run the below command:

```
# sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://IP Address/database --username root --password PASSWORD --table table_name --m 1
```

for importing the data from mysql database to  HDFS, I am getting the error:

> The auxService:mapreduce_shuffle does not exist.

Searched and browsed many sites, nothing helped.

How to get rid of this issue? Please let me know if any more inputs are required.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its an entry that you are missing in yarn-site.xml. Apply those entries in both namenodes and datanodes. If you read this http://dataheads.wordpress.com/2013/11/21/hadoop-2-setup-on-64-bit-ubuntu-12-04-part-1/ , you will see that yarn-site.xml **must have** this entries:

```
 <property>
     <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
    <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.mapreduce_shuffle.class</name>
    <value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler</value>
  </property>
```

Be careful when you write **aux-services**, because the "-" in the middle it's probably getting you that problem.

Comment: The two property entries present in yarn-site.xml as per the above URL are configured in my setup but still I am getting the same error.

Comment: Don't forget to restart yarn after editing yarn-site.xml.